# "AssertionError: {} == {}" in mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I get in one of my mocha tests for

```
assert.equal(result, {});
```

the following error:

```
AssertionError: {} == {}
```

How can I test for an empty object?

Comment: use `assert.deepEqual()`  

Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14545989/405788

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps look at the object's keys

```
assert.equal(Object.keys(result).length, 0);
```